# Custom prefix using mysql & node.js

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, discord.js

> ```
> var prefix = `SELECT S_PREFIX FROM ServerConfigs WHERE S_ID = ${message.guild.id}`;  
> connection.query(prefix, function (err, result, fields) {  
> if (err) return console.log(err);  
> let res = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result[0].S_PREFIX));
> const serverPREFIX = res;
> ```

It works but sometimes it writes me an error to console.
The error looks like this:
**TypeError: Cannot read property 'S_PREFIX' of undefined**

Could anybody help me please? Just started learning MYSQL.

Answer (score 0):

`result[0]` is `undefined`, which means that your SQL query returned no results, meaning that there were no rows with the `S_ID` being `message.guild.id`. Just check that the result array is not empty.

```
var prefix = `SELECT S_PREFIX FROM ServerConfigs WHERE S_ID = ${message.guild.id}`;
connection.query(prefix, function (err, result, fields) {
  if (err) return console.log(err);
  if (result.length < 1) {
    console.log(`No results for S_ID = ${message.guild.id}`)
    return;
  }
  let res = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result[0].S_PREFIX));
  const serverPREFIX = res;
```